# Bytes from string from bytes not equals origin bytes

Tags: c#, string, encryption, encoding, byte

I have an encryption algorithm (RSA) and trying to make it able to encrypt and decrypt text of any length, the problem I faced is somewhy after encryption of block of bytes, if I convert is to string (using `Encoding.ASCII.GetString`) and then go back (with `GetBytes`) - I don't get the same array of bytes, same with UTF8, I'm not really into encodings, can someone help how can I solve this problem, so I can convert encrypted bytes into string and pass it to decryption algorithm and it will get proper bytes?

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 0xe1, 0xde, 0x4a, 0x10, 0xea, 0x74, 0x8f, 0x18, 0xd7, 0x93, 0x04, 0x7a, 0x10, 0xb2, 0xa8, 0xfa, 0x11, 0x00, 0x7a, 0xfb, 0xcb,
                            0x19, 0xb7, 0xf5, 0x25, 0x26, 0x6d, 0xa0, 0x0d, 0xdc, 0xe5, 0x0a };
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", bytes));
// 255 222 74 16 234 116 143 24 215 147 4 122 16 178 168 250 17 0 122 251 203 25 183 245 37 38 109 160 13 220 229 10
byte[] bytes2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", bytes2));
// 63 63 74 16 63 116 63 24 63 4 122 16 63 63 63 17 0 122 63 63 25 63 63 37 38 109 63 13 63 63 10
byte[] bytes3 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", bytes3));
// 63 63 74 16 63 116 63 24 63 4 122 16 63 63 63 17 0 122 63 63 25 63 63 37 38 109 63 13 63 63 10
```

Array bytes I got from encrypting "hello world!" with 32 bytes key from my encryption algorithm, as you see, ascii nor utf8 to string and then back to bytes doesn't gives me back my original array of bytes somewhy

Comment: Why does your encryption/decryption algorithm takes a string?

Comment: It could be that your encrypted data contains all 256 different byte values, but the encoding you're using doesn't assign a character value to all 256 values. To me it sounds like you're doing something you shouldn't. If you really need a text representation of the encrypted data, the usual way to do that is to base64 encode the byte values.

Comment: cause my task is to make it encrypt text, i'm converting string to byte array, take blocks of it one byte smaller than my N (from public key), converting this block of bytes to biginteger and encrypting it

Comment: Try to boil your code down to the minimum code needed to show your problem and then edit your post to include the code. I think that would help a lot. Right now we're just guessing what the problem could be.

Comment: Don't use string encoding to encode a sequence of raw bytes into a string, none of the formats are safe and not intended for that purpose. Use Base64/85 instead, as in `Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)` and then `Convert.FromBase64String(s)` later to get back the original bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not supposed to use the Encoding.XYZ objects for converting sequences of bytes into strings unless those bytes actually make up a string in that encoding. Their purpose is to do the bytes-to-string conversion when you're reading text from any form of medium that serves bytes, such as FileStream or similar. However, those bytes actually have to be correctly encoded for the encoding you choose. You cannot convert arbitrary sequences of bytes to strings using these encodings. As you've already observed, they will mangle the result. You might get lucky for quite a few byte sequences, but if you're using any of the cryptographic secure encryption algorithms, that luck will run out immediately.

Instead, use something like Base64 or 85. Base64 is built into .NET, and if you have this code:

```
byte[] original = ...
string encoded = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(original);
byte[] decoded = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(encoded);
```

all you have to do is change to this:

```
byte[] original = ...
string encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(original);
byte[] decoded = Convert.FromBase64String(encoded);
```

Comment: After posting this I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate. Please find a duplicate link and I'd be happy to delete this answer.

Comment: this solved my problem, thanks, now i just convert input (to encryption) string from ascii, encrypting bytes, converting them to base64, then in decryption convert input string from base64, decrypt bytes and convert them back to ascii

Comment: Assuming the original string is pure ASCII, sure, but in 2020 I wouldn't bank on it. ASCII looses a lot of special characters and accents, I would use UTF8 instead. For instance, my name, would be mangled if it was in a string you ran through this encryption, because you used ASCII encoding.